# Drawing head detection bounding box in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, frame, bounding-box

I have scenario where I need to detect the `head` of a person. For this I am using person detection model and then using the person bounding box, I am extracting the head part of the person.

```
person_detector.setInput(blob)
person_detections = person_detector.forward()
boundingboxes = np.array([])
for i in np.arange(0, person_detections.shape[2]):
    person_det_confidence = person_detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    if person_det_confidence > 0.40:
        # extract the index of the class label from the
        # detections list
        idx = int(person_detections[0, 0, i, 1])

        # if the class label is not a person, ignore it
        if CLASSES[idx] != "person":
            continue

        # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box
        # for the object
        person_box = person_detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = person_box.astype("int")

        # Only append the person which are inside ROI
        if roix1 < startX < roix2:
            rects.append(person_box)

boundingboxes = np.array(rects)
boundingboxes = boundingboxes.astype(int)
person_rects = helper.non_max_suppression_fast(boundingboxes, 0.3)

head_rects = []

for (startX, startY, endX, endY) in person_rects:
    img = frame[startY: startY + endY, startX: startX + endX]
    (startX, startY, endX, endY) = detect_head(img)
    p = (startX, startY, endX, endY)
    head_rects.append(p)
```

In the above code `person_rects` contains the rect of person detected. We pass it to a function `detect_head` which returns the head bounding box which is saved in head_rects.

`head_rects` looks like below:

```
startX = 0
startY = 4
endX = 384
endY = 61
```

Now if I draw a rectangle using above coordinates:

```
cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

It is drawn incorrect:

[image]

In the above image you can see the red rectangle is drawn on top left side of the frame while it should be where lady is standing in frame. The reason for this is, the coordinates of the head detected is with respect to the person and not with respect to frame and thus while displaying it is drawn wrong. Can anyone please give me some idea on how can I correct it. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You are getting wrong points, rectangle is drawing correctly according to given points. Are you sure that the algorithm working properly?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Yes I am sure the algorithm is working fine because I saved the image of the head detected and it was correct. Reason for the rectangle being drawn wrong is explained in the question.

Comment: Then you should add x and y coordinates of left top corner of detected person rectangle to your head_rect corner coordinates

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk You are right, OR I should draw head bouding box with respect to person image like `cv2.rectangle(img, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)` instead of `cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)` where `img` is person image and not the full frame

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not simply using a face detection?

Comment: @Andreas Yes. I need to track people who are working in industries. Because of many large products around them, their complete body is not visible. Face is also not visible all the time, so if I start tracking based on face, I will loose it in next few frames and thus head is the only way through which I can keep tracking a person and calculate it dwell time

Comment: Good thing is I have been able to track the head perfectly fine and its working good.